# Webpack multiple jsx compile setting

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am trying to load multiple .jsx files to compile into one.

Right now, we have app.jsx file and home.jsx file in the same directory.
I want to compile them using webpack and combine the two outputs into one file.
It does compile into one at the moment, but the compiled code from home.jsx isn't imported first, so the routes do not know where to point to.

I've attached the app.jsx, home.jsx and the webpac.config.js.
Please help :)

App.jsx

```
import React from "react";

var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;
var Home = require('./home.jsx');

define(["./home.jsx"], function (){

})

App = React.createClass({
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hire Monster App</h1>
                <RouteHandler/>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

var routes = (
    <Route handler={App}>
        <Route path="/" handler={mainPage}/>
        <Route path="login" handler={Home.jobs}/>
        <Route path="jobs" handler={Home.jobs}/>
    </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, Router.HashLocation, (Root) => {
    React.render(<Root/>, document.body);
});
```

home.jsx

```
import React from "react";
var mainPage;
module.exports = React.createClass({
      render: function () {
        return (
          <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        );
      }
    });

/*
module.export ={}
    var mainPage = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            return <h1>Welcome!</h1>;
        }
    });

    var login = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            return <h1>Login</h1>;
        }
    });

    var jobs = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            return <h1>Jobs</h1>;
        }
    });
*/
```

webpack.config

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        bundle1:["./src/app.jsx","./src/home.jsx"]
    },
    output: {
        path: "../public/javascripts",
        filename: "hire.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.jsx$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A couple of things to consider.

1. Why the AMD style `define([])`, especially when you already `require()` it immediately before?
2. You're mixing the ES6 module format and the CommonJS module format in several places. For consistency I'd suggest the following: If you use `import` you should use `export default` instead of `module.exports` and never use `require()` or `define()`
3. Usually the idea of an entry file is a single entry point which you'd use as a `<script>` tag. As long as that entry point contains an `import` or `require()` to the other file it should be included and additional configuration inside of `webpack.config.js` is not needed.

#### Specific suggestions:

**First** You can probably remove all of the following from your config.

```
entry: {
    bundle1:["./src/app.jsx","./src/home.jsx"]
},
output: {
    path: "../public/javascripts",
    filename: "hire.js"
}
```

Instead be very specific with your `webpack` call like this:

`webpack ./src/app.jsx --output-file ../public/javascript/hire.js`

Until you wrap your head around all of the config options this is probably simplest.

**Next** Completely remove the `define()` call. This is not needed.

**Finally** Switch all `require()` statements to use `import` and your `module.exports` to `export default`

Once you do that if it doesn't work update the code with that and we'll think through it!